# How can I write this sum $ S = z^0 + z^2 + z^4 + ... + z^{2020} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, contest-math

let **z** be $ z = e^{i\cdot \pi/2021} $

and  $ S = z^0 + z^2 + z^4 + ... + z^{2020} $

I figured that S could be written in this way $ S = \sum_{k=0}^{1010} z^{2k} $

But I need to write S in this way $ S = 1/(1-z) $

I really got stuck may someone help me?

Comment: It's a geometric series whose common ratio is $z^2$. Apply the formula.

Comment: In the sigma notation, $k$ should run up to $1010$. To answer the question, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: Well, if you need to write $S$ as $S= 1/(1-z)$ then write it as $S=1/(1-z)$. But that wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @Malek Note that $z^{2k} = [z^2]^k$

Comment: @chhro I know the formula when for z but not for z², may you show me how It's done?

Comment: I just want to clarify about what @chhro said, is that it only works if the sum goes to infinity.

Comment: Hint:  If $a = z^2$ then $z^{2k} = (z^2)^k = a^k$.

Comment: @Gary I corrected it
Thank you!

Comment: @fleablood I need to prove it before I used it

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the hint!
I got it

Comment: "I know the formula when for z but not for z², may you show me how It's done? "  The formula is $\sum_{k=0}^{n} pinkhonkityhonkhonk^k= \frac {pinkhonkityhonkhonk^{n+1} - 1}{pinkhonkityhonkhonk-1}$ So if $pinkhonkityhonkhonk = z$ and $n=2020$ you know what to do.  So just do the exact same think if $pinkhonkityhonkhonk = z^2$ and $n =1010$.

Comment: @fleablood use **\text{pink...}** ;)

Comment: @Houston this sum doesn't go to infinity It's a finite

Comment: @fleablood Oh got it!
also, what is that   "pinkhonkityhonkhonk"?
I'm still new to this community, I don't get the reference

Comment: "this sum doesn't go to infinity It's a finite"  Right so you *can't* us the if $|a|< 1$ then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{1-a}$ formula.  You must use the $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {a^{n+1} -1}{a-1}$ (which works for all $a \ne 1$; not just $|a|< 1|$).  So let $a = z^2$ and $n=1010$.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you <3

Comment: There is no referenence.  $pinkhonkityhonkhonk$ is any bleeping thing you want it to be.  I use it because I make it up off the top of my head.  I use it *BECAUSE* it is ridiculous and stupid and obviously doesn't mean anything.  If you can plug in *anything* you can plug in $z^2$.  It's just a placeholder.

Comment: ohh xD, Our teacher uses "pigs" when putting formulas

Comment: For example: if $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 3$ then $f(3) = 3^2+2*3+3$ and $f(-17)=(-17)^2+2(-17) + 3$ and $f(x^2) = (x^2)^2 + 2(x^2) + 3$ and $f(y^3-17\sqrt w)= (y^3-17\sqrt w)^2 + 2(y^3-17\sqrt w) + 3$ and $f(pinkhonkityhonkhonk)=pinkhonkityhonkhonk^2 +2*pinkhonkityhonkhonk +3$.  The point I'm making is placeholders are just that; placeholders and *anything* can go in them.  If $z$ can go into them, then $z^2$ can go into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ S = 1 + z^2 + z^4 + ... + z^{2020}= \sum_{r=0}^{1010} z^{2k} = \sum_{r=0}^{1010} (z^2)^{k} =\frac{z^{2022}-1}{z^2-1}=\frac{z.z^{2021}-1}{z^2-1}$$

It's pretty obvious from here

Comment: Yess!
Thanks sir <3

Comment: Glad you understood $ ^{\cdot} \smile ^{\cdot}$

Answer (score 0):

IF your sum were infinite, then you'd have the right formula.  Since the sum is finite, the formula is

$$S = \frac{1-z^{2022}}{1-z^2}.$$

Since $z^{2021} = 1$, this should be easy to simplify.

Comment: How can I know if the sum is infinite or finite?